# How to get the google plus profile name, photo URL and country using the link to the user profile

Tags: php, android, api, google-plus

I'm trying to implement an Android App with a list of users, and I just have the links from their g+ profiles.

I would get these information:
Profile name
Profile Photo URL
Profile Country

I saw some ways to make this using the Google+ PHP API, but these ways need the user's ID... and I haven't the IDs.

I saw, for example, this test:
https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get

But don't works with the custom ID. (like +FelipePorgeXavier)

Which is the best way to make this? (Without needs user login)

[image: Profile List]

Comment: `people.get` works fine with `+FelipePorgeXavier`. There is currently an issue with rate limiting on the docs example where it only works once every dozen attempts.

Comment: But, Can I use people.get without login?

Comment: You can use an [API key](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#apikey) that is not user specific.

Answer (score 1):

Just send **me** as the ID

> userId    string   The ID of the person to get the profile for. The
>   special value **"me"** can be used to indicate the authenticated user.

will return all the information on the current authenticated user.

If its not the current authenticated user you are after you can use [people.Search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search) to search after the user by there name, but you may get more than one.

sorry i cant help you with the android code for this.